# the var doesn't become global but remains local

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, global-variables

From the following snippet i try to test `NewGlobalRef` and try to make `clsStr` global after declaring it in the local scope of `if` block.

```
jstring Java_Package_LocalAndGlobalReference_returnGlobalReference
 (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
if(1) {
    printf("In function make global reference\n");
    jclass clsStr ;
    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"java/lang/String");
    if( cls == NULL)
        return NULL;
    // create a global reference of clsStr
    clsStr = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,cls);
    // Delete the local reference, which is no longer userful
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,cls);
    if(clsStr == NULL)
        return NULL;
}
 return clsStr; // statement 31
}
```

When i run the above snippet i get the following errors :

```
W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\LGR\LGR.c:31: error: 'clsStr' undeclared (first use in this function)
W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\LGR\LGR.c:31: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\LGR\LGR.c:31: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Why do i get the error saying that `clsStr` is undefined when i have made that var global using the satement `clsStr = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,cls)` ?

Comment: why the if(1) { ... } thing ?

Comment: @SirDarius just for testing purposes. why do you have to ask such questions ? :)

Comment: this is pure curiosity, because well, I don't see the practical purpose of such a test, since you can create local naming scopes just by using { and }.

Comment: @SirDarius they were actually not in my mind !

Comment: See my answer to [your duplicate post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597968/what-is-global-about-the-clsstr-variable-which-is-clsstr-env-newglobalref)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare a variable in a block (in this case, you declare `clsStr` in the block if the `if(1) { ... }` statement), the scope of that variable (and its lifetime) is that block. That means it doesn't exist when you `return clsStr` *after* the block.

You can either

- move the return statement inside the block, or
- declare the variable `clsStr` before the `if(1) { ... }` statement

> when i have made that var global using the statement `clsStr = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,cls)`

That is a misunderstanding - you can't make a variable global by assignment; you do that by declaration in the global scope. You can initialize a variable by assignment, but that doesn't have anything to do with its scope.

Comment: then what is `NewGlobalRef(env,cls)` meant for ?

Comment: NewGlobalRef creates a global **Java** reference, it has nothing to do with the C implementation.

Comment: That doesn't affect the C compiler in any way; instead, it instructs the JNI *not* to free the reference once the JNI call has finished. IIUC, the difference between "global" and "local" references is that global references must always be freed by the programmer (and the object will not be deleted until the programmer says), while local references will be subject to GC once the JNI call finished. More info: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html

Comment: @SirDarius How can a global **Java** reference inside the native code be helpful,,,we can't even return that ?

Comment: @program-o-steve: Read the page I linked. Basically, the global reference is useful for ensuring that it (and its contents) will survive to the next JNI invocation.

Comment: @jpalecek aah..can you also explain _"...will survive to the next JNI invocation"_ ?

Comment: @program-o-steve: That means the GC won't delete it before you call the same method from Java again.