# what is global about the clsStr variable which is "clsStr = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,cls)"?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, global-variables

Global Reference in JNI is said to be a reference that has to be manually freed by the programmer. It has nothing to do with the c context. so a code like :

```
{
    jclass clsStr = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,cls); 
}

return clsStr;
```

will give an error saying that `clsStr` is  *undefined / undeclared*. I understand this. But what i don't understand is the **use** of these type of references.

What is global about `clsStr` in the above code ? How this variable can be useful in future or after the call returns ?  I also read that *"Basically, the global reference is useful for ensuring that it (and its contents) will survive to the next JNI invocation"* but i don't understand this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [the var doesn't become global but remains local](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596766/the-var-doesnt-become-global-but-remains-local)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you're allowed to hold on to the reference you get from `NewGlobalRef()` across multiple calls to the native mathod. The reference will remain valid until you explicitly call `DeleteGlobalRef()`.

This is in contrast to [local references](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html):

> A local reference is valid only within the dynamic context of the native method that creates it, and only within that one invocation of the native method. All local references created during the execution of a native method will be freed once the native method returns.

If you store a global reference in a variable that's allowed to go out of scope before you call `DeleteGlobalRef()`, you leak memory. The following is an example of that:

```
{
    jclass clsStr = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,cls); 
}
```

Comment: how is _weak global variable_ different from _global variable_ ? I read that **Unlike global references, weak global references do not keep the underlying object from being garbage collected** but i don't understand this statement

Comment: @program-o-steve: A *weak* reference can go NULL if the garbage collector decides to collect the object. If you read that document further, it explains this in some detail.

Answer (score 1):

> Global Reference in JNI is said to be a reference that has to be
>   manually freed by the programmer. It has nothing to do with the c
>   context.

No it isn't. That is a terrible misquote from the [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242). Here's what it really says:

> The JNI divides object references used by the native code into two
>   categories: local and global references. Local references are valid
>   for the duration of a native method call, and are automatically freed
>   after the native method returns. Global references remain valid until
>   they are explicitly freed.

Nothing in JNI can alter the semantics of the C programming language.